# NetSuite - Unable to set default values on inventory transfer via client script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Perhaps the most simple solution I am missing here, but this small script is failing to default the "From location" and "to location" fields on page init of the "inventory transfer" record. The "subsidiary" field does however set successfully.

Here's my code - any ideas about what I could be doing wrong?

```
        function pageInit(scriptContext) {
        if (scriptContext.mode !== 'create')
            return;

        var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;

        currentRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'subsidiary',
            value: 6
        });
        currentRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'location',
            value: 10
        });
        currentRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'transferlocation',
            value: 17
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough information to answer this question. Are you getting any errors in the console and are the options that you're specifying available to select from after the page is loaded? 

I recommend updating the script to include a console.log to see whether or not the function is being called correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes - I have added a console.log line at the beginning: console.log('function works'), and is fine. I have double-checked the ids in the LOCATION list and they do exist with the selected subsidiary. I should add that the SUBSIDIARY is auto-populating successfully. When I do the same operation via the UI, I am able to select the mentioned locations (10 & 17) after selecting subsidiary 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the location lists aren't populated at the time the `pageInit` function is called. What I recommend doing is moving the location `setValue` calls into a `postSourcing` function so that they are triggered after the subsidiary is set and the location lists are sourced.